# Trying to understand how variable swapping is used to update a 2d grid

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following code used to simulate 2D diffusion.

```py
import time

grid_shape = (640, 640)

@profile
def evolve(grid, dt, out, D=1.0):
    xmax, ymax = grid_shape  # width and height of the matrix

    for i in range(xmax):
        for j in range(ymax):
            grid_xx = (
                grid[(i + 1) % xmax][j] + grid[(i - 1) %
                                               xmax][j] - 2.0 * grid[i][j]
            )

            grid_yy = (
                grid[i][(j + 1) % ymax] + grid[i][(j - 1) %
                                                  ymax] - 2.0 * grid[i][j]
            )

            out[i][j] = grid[i][j] + D * dt * (grid_xx + grid_yy)

def run_experiment(num_iterations):
    # setting up the initial conditions
    xmax, ymax = grid_shape
    next_grid = [[0.0] * ymax for x in range(xmax)]
    grid = [[0.0] * ymax for x in range(xmax)]

    # initial conditions for simulating a drop of dye in the middle of the simulated region
    block_low = int(grid_shape[0] * 0.4)
    block_high = int(grid_shape[0] * 0.5)

    for i in range(block_low, block_high):
        for j in range(block_low, block_high):
            grid[i][j] = 0.005

    # Evolve the initial conditions
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # evolve modifies grid and next_grid in-place
        evolve(grid, 0.1, next_grid)
        grid, next_grid = next_grid, grid

    return time.time() - start


run_experiment(100)
```

Based on my understanding, evolve modifies next_grid in place, then grid is assigned with next_grid to reflect the updates at that iteration. But why is next_grid assigned with grid, which if I am not mistaken is the previous state of the grid?

Comment: Have you tried asking the original author?

Comment: I am not too familiar with actual CPython implementation, but maybe this is more efficient by overwriting instead of allocating new memory (and garbage collecting). I guess in the end, the author was accessing `grid` to get the final state. Still, as said above, the original author might know best what they intended.

Comment: I got this code from High Performant Python by Gorelick and Ozsvald. The code is indeed trying to show a memory efficient approach for updating a list of lists. It's just that next_grid = grid assignment is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: to use that no longer needed matrix as an output for next iteration.

As you wrote in comment to your answer:

> The code is indeed trying to show a memory efficient approach...

And swapping is meant to keep memory efficiency low.

In the algorithm you need two matrices in memory, one for input, one for output. Lets call starting matrix A0, and result of each consecutive evolve will be A1, A2, A3, etc.

- On first iteration, A0 is input, A1 is output. We need to prepare two matrices in memory.
- On second iteration A1 is input, A2 is output. A0 is no longer needed so we can use it to write A2 into it (instead of creating 3d matrix).
- On third iteration A2 is input, A3 is output. A1 is no longer needed so we can use it to write A3 into it
- and so on..

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down in an understandable way.